# "writing" tag slightly confusing?

Tags: discussion, ambiguous-tags

At first, I assumed that [writing](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) meant the act of writing something down. However, the tag wiki says

> Focused on the aspects peculiar to Japanese in its written form rather
>   than the spoken form.

If the tag is supposed to cover reading (not to be confused with [reading](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading)!) as well as writing, would [written](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/written) be less confusing?

For the record, the oldest question that currently uses [writing](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) is [How to write hiragana and katakana in Windows?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/289/how-to-write-hiragana-and-katakana-in-windows) . I assume it was the creator of the tag, but I can't be certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in all of my reading of Japanese, "Japanese in its written form" is usually referred to as "written Japanese". I don't think I've ever even heard of it referred to as "writing". I think that in addition to being unambiguous, I think the new tag is much more common.

Comment: how about "literary Japanese"?

Comment: I think there is a good place for a "literary Japanese" tag, but I think that is more constricted than "written". Written would include many of the types of things that could be in literary japanese (but not all), but would also include questions about things  like writing style in newspapers and academic reports.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, “writing” indeed means written text as opposed to “speech” (spoken text) in linguistics.  However, I agree that “writing” is ambiguous.  How about [written-text](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/written-text)?

Comment: Is "written-text" a bit verbose?

Comment: @Andrew: Why? .